# Why does my button disappear from my borderlayout when I add an actionListener to it?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, border-layout

I am writing the back end code for my java project which is implementing a fitness logger. For some reason when I put the actionListener function to a button in my Border Layout then the button disappears.

I tried setting the function in different places in the constructor.

```
public class Buttons extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Menu");
      JPanel MyPanel= new JPanel();

      JButton b1= new JButton("Daily Logger");
      JButton b2= new JButton("View Weekly Logs");
      JButton b3= new JButton("Weight Calculator");
      JButton b4= new JButton("BMI Calculator");
      JButton b5= new JButton("Log Out");

      public Buttons(){
        MyPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        MyPanel.add(b1, "North");
        MyPanel.add(b2, "Center");
        MyPanel.add(b3, "East");
        MyPanel.add(b4, "West");
        MyPanel.add(b5, "South");

        b1.addActionListener(this);
        add(b1);

        frame.getContentPane().add(MyPanel, "North");
        frame.setSize(500,115);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Buttons();
      }


      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          String command = e.getActionCommand();

          if(command.equals("Daily Logger"))
              myMethod();
      }

      public void myMethod() {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Onto the next step");
      }
}
```

I expected the button to show up in the border layout when I add the actionListener function but it disappears. If the button did work as it should it should implement the myMethod() function. My main goal is to show my JTable that I created in another class to show up when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

```
add(b1);
```

Should be removed. The code has already added it via:

```
MyPanel.add(b1, "North");
```

---

A `BorderLayout` accommodates up to five components, each in a separate layout constraint. If a component is added twice, in different areas, it faces two problems:

1. A component can only appear in one place.
2. The component 'overwrites' the original component added to that area of the layout.

---

More general tips:

1. Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.
2. For better help sooner, add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). **Note: The posted code only needed appropriate `import` statements to be an MRE / SSCCE.**
3. `MyPanel.add(b3, "East");` re `East`

   - There are constants for this. E.G. `BorderLayout.EAST`. always use the constants for compile time checking.
   - But `BorderLayout.LINE_END` is sensitive to the locale. It will appear on the RHS for left to right languages, and the left for right to left languages.
4. All Swing & AWT GUIs should be created & updated on the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).
5. The code both extends and keeps a reference to, `JFrame`. Keep the latter, ditch the former.
6. Be sure to add the `java` (language) and `swing` (GUI toolkit) tags to questions! The only reason I saw this was because I (extraordinarily) checked the question listing for the `jframe` tag! To the best of my recollection, it's the first time I've ***ever*** checked that tag's question listing. Even more ironic, it did not make the list of 5 tags I saw as being *most relevant* to this question.
7. `frame.getContentPane().add(..` can be shortened to `frame.add(..` since Java 1.5.
8. `frame.setSize(500,115);` should better be `frame.pack();`, since 500 x 115 is no better than a guess, and will be 'wrong' for different OS' (the size of the content pane will change due to different frame decorations per system).